# How to add attribute with binding expression from inside directive link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can one add an expression to the `element` parameter passed to a directive's `link` function?

For example, inside the directive I want to add this:
`element.setAttribute('ng-disabled','{{disabled}}');`

Where disabled is a property on the directive `scope`.

The directive does not have a template, it just uses the `element` parameter passed in.

I'm thinking I should re-$compile the element using the directive scope, but I'm not sure if that will also re-compile the directive as well.

I know I can `$watch` disabled and toggle the disabled property on the element, but I'm trying to understand if I can add dynmic attributes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### You can pass your someValue using scope.

In template:

```
parameter="someValueCanPassTo"
```

In directive:

```
scope: {
    parameter: '='
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    $watch('parameter', function() {
        element.attr('my-attr', scope.parameter);
    });
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't be binding though, would it? :)

Comment: I edited the answer. using `$watch` will let them be binding.

Comment: Thanks, but I already said I know I can `$watch` properties to get binding. I am just curious to see if it's possible to add an attribute to an already compiled DOM element and re-compile it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute using `element.attr('attrName', 'attrVal')`. If you want the attribute to be automatically updated, then you should use:

```
$scope.$watch(attrs.attrName, function(val){
  element.attr('disabled', val);
});
```

Yes, re-compiling the element will cause re-compile of the directive (causing an infinite loop).

Also, there is already a [ng-disabled](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive - so not sure why you are trying to re-create it.

Comment: I know that, I wrote about that on the last paragraph. And I can't use `ngDisabled` because I don't control the template inside the directive.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to add an attr to an element inside the template (that you don't control) - and then have that attr trigger a directive?

Comment: The directive has no template. I want to add the `ng-disabled="..."` attribute on the `element` on which the directive is applied to and have Angular compile just that attribute because the rest is already compiled.